# Error in generalized linear mixed model cross-validation: The value in 'data[[cat_col]]' must be constant within each ID

Tags: r, cross-validation, mixed-models

I am trying to conduct a 5-fold cross validation on a generalized linear mixed model using the groupdata2 and cvms packages. This is the code I tried to run:

```
data <- groupdata2::fold(detect, k = 5,
                            cat_col = 'outcome',
                            id_col = 'bird') %>% 
                            arrange(.folds)

cvms::cross_validate(
data,
"outcome ~ sex  + year + season + (1 | bird) + (1 | obsname)",
family="binomial",
fold_cols = ".folds",
control = NULL,
REML = FALSE)
```

This is the error I receive:

```
Error in groupdata2::fold(detect, k = 4, cat_col = "outcome", id_col = "bird") %>%  : 
  1 assertions failed:
 * The value in 'data[[cat_col]]' must be constant within each ID.
```

In the package vignette, the following explanation is given: "A participant must always have the same diagnosis (‘a’ or ‘b’) throughout the dataset. Otherwise, the participant might be placed in multiple folds." This makes sense in the example. However, my data is based on the outcome of resighting birds, so outcome varies depending on whether the bird was observed on that particular survey. Is there a way around this?

Reproducible example:

```
bird <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3)
outcome <- c(0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1)
df <- data.frame(bird, outcome)
df$outcome <- as.factor(df$outcome)
df$bird <- as.factor(df$bird)

data <- groupdata2::fold(df, k = 5,
cat_col = 'outcome',
id_col = 'bird') %>% 
arrange(.folds)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full documentation says:

> `cat_col`: Name of categorical variable to balance between folds.
> E.g. when predicting a binary variable (a or b), we usually
> want both classes represented in every fold.
> N.B. If also passing an ‘`id_col`’, ‘`cat_col`’ should be
> constant within each ID.

So in this case, where outcome varies within individual birds (`id_col`), you simply can't specify that the folds be balanced within respect to the outcome. (I don't 100% understand this constraint in the software: it seems it should be possible to do at least approximate balancing by selecting groups (birds) with a balanced range of outcomes, but I can see how it could make the balancing procedure a lot harder).

In my opinion, though, the importance of balancing outcomes is somewhat overrated in general. Lack of balance would mean that some of the simpler metrics in `?binomial_metrics` (e.g. accuracy, sensitivity, specificity) are not very useful, but others (balanced accuracy, AUC, aic) should be fine.

A potentially greater problem is that you appear to have (potentially) crossed random effects (i.e. `(1|bird) + (1|obsname)`). I'm guessing `obsname` is the name of an observer: if some observers detected (or failed to detect) multiple birds and some birds were detected/failed by multiple observers, then there may be no way to define folds that are actually independent, or at least it may be very difficult.

Comment: In terms of crossed random effects, both statements are true - all observers have detected/failed to detect multiple birds, and all birds were detected/failed to be detected by multiple observers. I didn’t realize this was problematic. Does this mean that I should drop one of these effects from the model, or does it only become a problem when I get to the cross-validation step?

Comment: Follow-up question: I have used cross-validation in the past on fixed effects models without issue, but I have been tinkering with cross-validation for a glmm for days, and it is not nearly as straightforward. Is there a better option to measuring predictive performance for a glmm? I have read through many glmm-related cross-validation posts, but have yet to find anything that walks through an example from start to finish.

Comment: The model with crossed random effects is certainly appropriate. Appropriate CV for models with grouping is definitely more challenging. I don't know the answer to your question about assessing predictive performance for mixed models (especially with crossed random effects): it might make a good question for [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to utilize the new `collapse_groups()` function in `groupdata2 v2.0.0` instead of `fold()` for this. It allows you to take existing groups (e.g. `bird`) and collapse them to fewer groups (e.g. folds) with attempted balancing of multiple categorical columns, numeric columns, and factor columns (number of unique levels - though the same levels might be in multiple groups).

It does not have the constraints that `fold()` does with regards to changing outcomes, but on the other hand does not come with the same "guarantees" in the "non-changing outcome" context. E.g. it does not guarantee at least one of each outcome levels in all folds.

You need more birds than the number of folds though, so I've added a few to the test data:

```r
bird <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,
          4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7)
outcome <- c(0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,
             0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1)
df <- data.frame(bird, outcome)
df$outcome <- as.factor(df$outcome)
df$bird <- as.factor(df$bird)

# Combine 'bird' groups to folds
data <- groupdata2::collapse_groups(
  data = df, 
  n = 3, 
  group_cols="bird", 
  cat_col="outcome", 
  col_name = ".folds"
) %>% 
  arrange(.folds)

# Check the balance of the relevant columns
groupdata2::summarize_balances(
  data=data, 
  group_cols=".folds", 
  cat_cols="outcome"
)$Groups

> # A tibble: 3 × 6
>   .group_col .group `# rows` `# bird` `# outc_0` `# outc_1`
>   <fct>      <fct>     <int>    <int>      <dbl>      <dbl>
> 1 .folds     1            14        3          7          7
> 2 .folds     2            10        2          6          4
> 3 .folds     3            10        2          4          6
```

`summarize_balances()` shows us that we created 3 folds with 14 rows in the first fold and 10 in the other folds. There are 3 unique bird levels in the first fold and 2 in the others (normally only unique within the group, but here we know that birds are only in one group, as that is how `collapse_groups()` works with its `group_cols` argument).
The outcome variable (here `# outc_0` and `# outc_1`) are somewhat decently balanced.

With larger datasets, you might want to run multiple collapsings and choose the one with the best balance from the summary. That can be done by adding `num_new_group_cols = 10` to `collapse_groups()` (for even better results, enable the `auto_tune` setting) and then listing all the created group columns when running `summarize_balances()`.

Hope this helps you or others in a similar position. The constraint in `fold()` is hard to get around with its current internal approach, but `collapse_groups` hopefully does the trick in those cases.

See more https://rdrr.io/cran/groupdata2/man/collapse_groups.html